# code coverage is not happening in sonarqube for go lang

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, github-actions

Im using github action for sonarqube. My project is golang. after build on the sonarqube dashboard code coverage is showing 0.0%. Can you please tell me how to fix the issue.

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: SonarQube Scan
      uses: kitabisa/sonarqube-action@master
      with:
        host: http://IPaddress
        login: ${{ secrets.token }}
        projectBaseDir: ./
        projectKey: myprokey
        projectName: mypro
        sonar.sources: .
        #sonar.exclusions: "**/*_test.go"
        sonar.tests: /xxxx/xxxxx/pubsubgossip_test/gossip_test.go
```

how can i pass argument for the test files which exists in my repo.

Answer (score 0):

May be my question has some answer to you,
[Integration test code coverage report for Go lang project in SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305207/integration-test-code-coverage-report-for-go-lang-project-in-sonarqube)

**You have to perform test**, record the test report and coverage report in some file and then make SonarQube digest your report. **SonarQube cannot run test, add a step that runs the test.**

Here is a sample project and source code so that you can check the whole range of parameters used:
https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=io.sonarcloud.examples.go-sqscanner-travis-project
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud_example_go-sqscanner-travis

Answer (score -1):

this is how it's configured in my project:

```
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/__tests__/**
sonar.sources=src
```