# Integration test code coverage report for Go lang project in SonarQube

Tags: go, sonarqube, sonarcloud

Installed cover tool with following command:
`go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover`

I'm able to run unit test and update the test and coverage result in Sonar with following config and method (all test are present in project root directory) :

Run test: `go test -coverprofile coverage.out -json > report.json`

sonar-project.properties:

```
#sonar server and project prop
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=**/*_test.go
sonar.tests=.
sonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.out
sonar.go.tests.reportPaths=report.json
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go
```

But there are some integration test, I'm not able to include those reports, have any one tried running automated functional testing and updated those reports in sonar for go lang?

I checked previous question posted, was not helpful since it didn't talk about integration/functional test: [code coverage is not happening in sonarqube for go lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791957/code-coverage-is-not-happening-in-sonarqube-for-go-lang)

Comment: FYI, `go tool cover` is part of the Go toolchain since Go 1.5. `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover` is unmaintained.