# How to tell Sonar to use my LCOV file for Code Coverage for GOLANG GO

Tags: go, sonarqube, bazel, sonarqube-scan, sonarcloud

Team,
I am generating go coverage and converting them to html to view in Jenkins. but I want to ship the LCOV file .dat to sonarqube. is there a way? like set a key value in `sonar-project.properties`

```
./bazel $BAZEL_STARTUP_OPTS coverage $BAZEL_OPTS $BAZEL_EXTRA_OPTS //src/services/discovery/... \
    --combined_report=lcov \
    --test_output=errors --test_verbose_timeout_warnings | tee /tmp/test_results.txt
```

for view on Jenkins I am converting LCOV `_coverage_report.dat` to html. But what I want to know if I can specify this in sonarqube.properties file either html or .dat lcov? to pick it up after scanning is done?
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305207/integration-test-code-coverage-report-for-go-lang-project-in-sonarqube) for java but not for GO

```
./bazel run @lcov//:bin/genhtml -- -o \coverage/discovery --ignore-errors source --no-source --function-coverage --branch-coverage --no-sort bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat || true
```

Comment: Am not sure and did not do any such so far. I would recommend you to refer this [implementation](https://github.com/Zetten/bazel-sonarqube) to analyse Bazel projects with SonarQube.